# How to change Page Title with Tag Manager in order to show different title in Analytics?

Tags: variables, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, page-title

The best solution would be to modify website that is being tracked and change it to generate more valuable Page Titles.

However, that isn't possible and I would like to use breadcrumbs to provide new Page Title for Analytics.

I've created new variable for title in Tag Manager and added a Trigger for it in a Tag.
And yet the Page Title isn't changing and therefore I ended up wondering should this tag be fired before Analytics tag?

EDIT:

I've now used it with Preview mode and I can see that it is at least trying to set a new value for title. However, the value seems a bit too "unescaped" and I think that there's some hidden characters that cause problems.

EDIT 2:

```js
function() {

    var a = jQuery('.breadcrumb_container a');

    delete a[0];

    var textValues = jQuery(a).map(function() {

        return jQuery(this).text();

    }).get();     

    var str = textValues.join(' > ');    

    return str;

}
```

Comment: Hi, you should modify the main pageview tag with field title and value your js variable. Did you try this?

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to create a new trigger. You should edit your existing pageview tag and set field of title as indicated below:

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I've tried but the title won't change. Perhaps there could be something wrong with the element to text processing and Google falls back to default value?

Comment: Can you confirm your GA Page View tag has value of title set to a new variable? You can use browser dev tools or  GTM's "preview" to see all variables sent

Comment: Hi! Just added additional information regarding this Preview method. Seems like it is trying but something goes wrong. I've now added custom javascript to take care of all hidden characters and now the debugger shows more "standard" results.

Comment: Could you provide code for this custom javascript + screenshot of it's setup in GTM ?

Comment: Please see above. Now it is generating much better titles so perhaps for now this is solved.